# Reading Integer user input in DataInputStream in java?

Tags: java, datainputstream

I am trying to get input from user using `DataInputStream`. But this displays some junk integer value instead of the given value.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Sequence {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);
    String str="Enter your Age :";
    System.out.print(str);
    int i=dis.readInt();
    System.out.println((int)i);
    }
}
```

And the output is

> Enter your Age :12
>
> 825363722

Why am I getting this junk value and how to correct the error?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that [`readInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readInt%28%29) does not behave as you might expect. It is not reading a string and convert the string to a number; it reads the input as **bytes*:

> Reads four input bytes and returns an int value. Let a-d be the first through fourth bytes read. The value returned is:
>
> ```
> (((a & 0xff) << 24) | ((b & 0xff) << 16) |  
> ((c & 0xff) << 8) | (d & 0xff))
> ```
>
> This method is suitable for reading bytes written by the writeInt method of interface DataOutput.

In this case, if you are in Windows and input `12` then enter, the bytes are:

- 49 - '1'
- 50 - '2'
- 13 - carriage return
- 10 - line feed

Do the math, 49 * 2 ^ 24 + 50 * 2 ^ 16 + 13 * 2 ^ 8 + 10 and you get 825363722.

If you want a simple method to read input, checkout `Scanner` and see if it is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the data from the `DataInputStream` you have to do the following -

```
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);
        StringBuffer inputLine = new StringBuffer();
        String tmp; 
        while ((tmp = dis.readLine()) != null) {
            inputLine.append(tmp);
            System.out.println(tmp);
        }
        dis.close();
```

The `readInt()` method returns the next four bytes of this input stream, interpreted as an int. According to the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readInt%28%29)

However you should have a look at **[Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this is use `Scanner`

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your Age :\n");
    int i=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);
String str="Enter your Age :";
System.out.print(str);
int i=Integer.parseInt(dis.readLine());
System.out.println((int)i);
}
```